# How to deserialize unknown properties with JSON-B?

Tags: java, json, resteasy, quarkus, jsonb-api

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON ([see API documentation](https://api.nasa.gov/assets/insight/InSight%20Weather%20API%20Documentation.pdf)) using the JSON-B implementation from Quarkus.

What bugs me here are the dynamically generated numeric keys for multiple JSON objects. I want to deserialize all unknown properties to a `Map<Long, MyObject>`. Simply declaring a Map inside the data object won't work.

Jackson seems to support exactly the desired behavior using the `@JsonAnySetter` annotation (see [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonanysetter.htm)).

What I could do is write my own `JsonbAdapter` to parse the unknown properties manually, but that seems like a riddiculous amount of work for such a simple task.

How can I deserialize unknown JSON properties to a Map with JSON-B?

```
{
  "634": {
    "AT": {
      "av": -61.082, 
      "ct": 314284, 
      "mn": -94.58, 
      "mx": -16.136
    }, 
    "First_UTC": "2020-09-07T15:29:16Z", 
    "HWS": {
      "av": 6.685, 
      "ct": 156912, 
      "mn": 0.452, 
      "mx": 17.887
    }, 
    "Last_UTC": "2020-09-08T16:08:49Z", 
    "PRE": {
      "av": 775.846, 
      "ct": 159956, 
      "mn": 746.3902, 
      "mx": 793.7311
    }, 
    "Season": "summer", 
  }, 
  "635": { ... }, 
  "636": { ... }, 
  "638": { ... }, 
  "sol_keys": [
    "634", 
    "635", 
    "636", 
    "638", 
  ], 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't answer your question directly but JSON-B doesn't have all the features Jackson has.

So if you miss a feature, you can just use Jackson: it's a first class citizen in the Quarkus world too. We have Jackson counterparts for each JSON-B extension.